# Pending Intent firing at Uneven Time

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have created three pending intents in a service class - one pending intent should fire in the morning, other one at the afternoon and the final one at the evening. 
When the pending intent is fired it calls the broadcast receiver where the broadcast receiver checks my sqlite database and if there are any items present in the database it will display a notification to the user to read the items in the sqlite database.

The thing is that the pending intents are been fired at unusual time rather that firing at right time. Please check the code below:

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

        Calendar calMor = new GregorianCalendar();
        calMor.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calMor.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 06);
        calMor.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calMor.set(Calendar.SECOND, 01);
        calMor.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);
        calMor.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        calMor.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

        Calendar calNoon = new GregorianCalendar();
        calNoon.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calNoon.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calNoon.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calNoon.set(Calendar.SECOND, 01);
        calNoon.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);
        calNoon.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        calNoon.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

        Calendar calEven = new GregorianCalendar();
        calEven.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calEven.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calEven.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calEven.set(Calendar.SECOND, 01);
        calEven.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);
        calEven.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        calEven.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

        Intent inteMor = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        AlarmManager alrmManagerMor = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Pending Intent for Morning
        PendingIntent penIntMor = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, inteMor, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        //set from today morning
        alrmManagerMor.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calMor.getTimeInMillis(), (24 * 60 * 60 + 1) * 1000,
                penIntMor);

        Intent inteAft= new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        AlarmManager alrmManagerAft = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Pending Intent for Afternoon
        PendingIntent penIntNoon = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, inteAft, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        //set from today afternoon
        alrmManagerAft.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calNoon.getTimeInMillis(), (24 * 60 * 60 + 1) * 1000,
                penIntNoon);

        Intent inteEve= new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        AlarmManager alrmManagerEve = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Pending Intent for Evening
        PendingIntent penIntEve = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, inteEve, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        //set from today evening
        alrmManagerEve.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calEven.getTimeInMillis(), (24 * 60 * 60 + 1) * 1000,
                penIntEve);

        System.out.println("Fired NotificationService");
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }/**/

}
```

This is the service where pending intents are fired to call the broadcast receiver.

**NotificationPublisher.java**

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private Cursor cursor;

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        System.out.println("Received Alarm");
        Log.i(TAG, "Received Alarm");

        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(context);
        dbAdapter.openDatabase();
        cursor = dbAdapter.getUpdatedRecords();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int records_count = cursor.getCount();

        if (records_count != 0) {

            int donecount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < records_count; i++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                String doneStr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.COL_DONE));
                if (doneStr.equals("false"))
                    donecount++;
            }

            if (donecount != 0) {

                // code for waking up the device in sleep mode
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                        PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
                wl.acquire();

                Intent inte = new Intent(context, NotificationDetailsActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, inte, 0);
                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("ThirteenDaysReminder")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                // hide the notification after its selected
                noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

                wl.release();
            }

        }

        dbAdapter.close();
        cursor.close();

    }


}
```

This is the Broadcast receiver class where it receives the broadcast and displays the notification to the user.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.co.ybn.thirteendaysreminder" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ItemDetailsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".NotificationDetailsActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".DoneActivity"/>

        <receiver android:name=".servicesreceivers.NotificationPublisher"/>
        <service android:name=".servicesreceivers.NotificationService"/>

        <receiver android:name=".servicesreceivers.MyStartServiceReceiver"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want the pending intent in the service class to be fired at right time to show the notifications instead of firing it at unusual time.

Comment: please define exactlky what "unusual time" means. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: I have set different pending intents to fire each at 6AM, 12PM and 6PM. But I'm receiving the notifications during the other that the times that I have set in the Pending Intents. I'm describing it as uneven time.

Comment: at what specific time do you see the notifications?

Comment: I see the notification a some random time.

Comment: You create an alarm that goes off at 6, 12 and 18 on the current day. If any of these times are in the past (for example, if you run the app at 13:00, the alarms will trigger immediately. otherwise i dont see why this shouldnt work.

Comment: can you suggest good solution for it?

Comment: You can check that the alarm times you generate are in the future. If not, add 24 hours to them.

Comment: As of API 19, repeating alarms may not be delivered at exactly the desired time. To see if this is causing your problem, try to set just a single alarm. Call `AlarmManager.set()` instead of `AlarmManager.setRepeating()`. If this solves your problem, you can simply set the alarm for the next day when the alarm for this day goes off.